# Choosing items from two groups to have equal weight

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have two groups of items. Each item has a weight attached to it. I want to find all combinations of group A items that would have equal weight (or close to equal with a certain tolerance) to the combinations of group B items. For example, item A1 + A2 weight is the same as B1, but A2 weight could also be B2 + B3. What approach can I use for this?

Comment: This sounds pretty similar to [the subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). I think a modification of the [dynamic programming solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) could work here.

Comment: If you want to find all such combinations, the output size can be exponential. So no algorithm will save you. Might as well brute force it. Or give up on finding all combinations.

Comment: I've been able to use the [polynomial time approximate algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm) for multiple subset sum problem to get a workable solution. But then my groups are bounded in size (< 20 items).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `2n` items, each of weight `1`. Each solution putting any `n` items in `A` and the remaining items in `B` would yield the optimal load difference `0`; however there are `2^n` such solutions.

This means that in general the number of optimal solutions can grow exponentially in the number of items. Consequently, it is impossible to find an algorithm (in the sense of 'runtime polynomially bounded in the number of items') for this problem unless some other restriction is done.

Dynamic programming algorithms here may render not so useful as they implicitly aim at pruning the search tree.